# Extract information through regexp

Tags: regex

I have a question about groups in a rule i created to extract dates from text.
Let's consider the following string:

```
fherfrefercr17hfeuetvbyeituew
```

The string is composed by everything at the beginning, then there is a number composed by one or two digits and then everything again. I need to extract only the number "17" from the string listed above.

With the following rule i extract only `7` and not `17`.

```
.*(\d{1,2}).*
```

Can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: Why does `*` have a backslash in front of it? I suspect you're doing this in a shell script? More context is always helpful, as it looks at first glance like you're looking for a literal asterisk.

Comment: ye it was an error due to copy and past from shell :-P. Thank you for having noted it so that i correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

Given your pattern:

```
.*(\d{1,2}).*
```

This works in the following way:

- `.*` Match any character any number of times

  - The quantifier here is considered to be *greedy* because it will match **as many characters as possible** so long as the pattern matches the string.
- `\d{1,2}` Since your pattern says to match 1 **or** 2 digits and the previous token is greedy, the regex is just going to match a single digit because this still satisfies the pattern (the previous token *stole* the first digit).

---

### Code

There are multiple ways you can fix this issue

#### Method 1

This will simply extract all numbers (1+ digits) from the string. If you want to only match 1 or two digits use `\d\d?` or `\d{1,2}` instead.

```
\d+
\d\d?
\d{1,2}
```

#### Method 2

This method turns the greedy quantifier `*` (in `.*`) into a lazy quantifier `.*?`. This will match any character any number of times, **but as few as possible**. The drawback to this method is that it's expensive because the engine needs to backtrack.

```
.*?\d{1,2}.*
```

#### Method 3

This method matches any non-digit character any number of times, then it matches one or two digits. This is likely the solution you're looking for.

```
\D*(\d{1,2}).*
```